# create a remote desktop to an ip address using crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ip-address, crm, remote-desktop

Hi I have created an entity in CRM 2011 that contains all the ip addresses on our network. On the form I have been asked to enable an option where you can click on the IP address and it will open a remote desktop session to that IP address. 
Can anyone help with this, thanks???

Answer (score 0):

The management portal for Windows Azure has this functionality for Virtual Machines. When you click the link, the Remote Desktop app opens and connects. You might set up a free account and look at the source to see how they are doing it.

My guess is that they generate an RDP file on the fly when you click that link. I'm not good enough at Javascript to know if that is possible solely on the client side.

If not, you could write a custom Plugin that would trigger on change of that IP address field. You'd generate the RDP file in the plugin using C# and attach it to that entity as a note, while saving the GUID of the attachment into another hidden field. Then write a custom web resource that displays the IP address but links directly to the attachment using the hidden GUID field.